# mp4 to avi/mpeg conversion

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, mpeg, avi

I'm trying to convert an mp4 video to play on a digital photo frame. The photo frame (Living Image Li1210) manual states:

The digital photo frame can playback MPEG1, MPEG2, MPEG4, and AVI (dependant upon codec) video formats.

And in the FAQs: The device only works with the avi/mpeg4 files taken by most digital cameras. It is also capable of playing some compressed AVI files, such as DivX and XviD videos... The best supported resolution of a photo or video is 480x234.

I've tried various options with ffmpeg such as

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf scale=480x234 out.avi
```

but can't seem to get anything but a blank screen on the photo frame.

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If you have a working file, share its readout by [Mediainfo](http://mediaarea.net). Use Text mode. Typically these OEM products are particular about the codec profile and tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apologies I'd being faffing with different scaling settings and must have got my files mixed up. The following (quoted in the question) does in fact work on this product - Living Images Li1210.

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf scale=480x234 out.avi
```

However the following scaling seemed to produce better results when converting from 1280x720 (youtube standard download)

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf scale=416x234 out.avi
```

And I think this addition from [this question](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20399/whats-the-best-way-to-convert-mp4-to-avi) produced a slight improvement

```
ffmpeg -i in.mp4 -q:v 6 -vcodec mpeg4 -vf scale=416x234 out.avi
```

Comment: In the absence of a `q:v` or bitrate specification, ffmpeg defaults to 200 kb/s for `mpeg4`. Your first scaling is disproportionate relative to the source. Your 2nd isn't.